# Postgres serialization versus new row versus NoSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, mongodb, database-design

I'm in the process of building a Rails application that stores custom data sets.  More specifically I'm storing an archive of leaderboards.  Leaderboards each have a set of LeaderboardEntries which can have custom fields (in other words not all Leaderboards have the same format).

Quick example:

```
Leaderboard 1 (Fields)
-------------
7_day_exponential_moving_average
total_count

Leaderboard 2 (Fields)
-------------
10_day_exponential_moving_average
total_count
```

Right now I'm serializing all the leaderboard entries to a field in Leaderboard called "data".  The result is I perform calculations on upwards of 30,000 objects, and store the results in a single field.

I'm starting to see there's a flaw to this when performing calculations asynchronously (I need to wait for all calculations to finish, monitor whether they are done, and then store all the data) and it appears as though creating a separate model called LeaderboardEntry would make more sense.  What I'm wondering about is the performance hit of storing and querying 30,000 distinct objects versus storing all 30,000 entries in a single field as I'm already doing.

I figured one request with one response would perform far better.  (i.e.

```
SELECT serialized_data FROM leaderboards WHERE leaderboard_id=123  <-- 1 row with a very large field
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboard_entries WHERE leaderboard_id=123 <-- 30,000 rows with small sets of data
```

Is my assumption that storing it in a serialized field correct?  Or would storing the entries individually not be that big of a deal?  One other thought I've had here: it may be even more efficient to use a nosql solution like MongoDB and then I can sort by the leaderboard_entry fields and limit the results to small quantities (50 results at a time).

Ultimately I'll be generating upwards of 1 million leaderboard entries (for 20+ leaderboards) per day and I'm simply trying to figure out the most efficient way of storing them.

Thanks!

Comment: It is good to look a step ahead: how you will be accessing the data once it is there in the DB? Will you ever need to access it by the portion that is only a small part of your serialized field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big serialized field will certainly be more efficient to store and retrieve than a bunch of small entries (Postgres will store the whole thing as a CLOB). That said, this is almost certainly a premature optimization. The advantage of normalized data is significant - you can step over your 30k-row query in segments by using `select where field > xxx and field < yyy`, which will make your access times very fast. Postgres can do operations on lots of small objects extremely efficiently. If your data is only semi-structured, have a look at the 'hstore' and JSON datatypes, which postgres can inspect with queries.

This doesn't seem to be a large enough question to contemplate a switch in databases - MongoDB won't have any immediate advantages here. Mostly the sticking point will be in how you design your queries for data access. Selecting partial datasets using good indexes will always be faster than doing a big open-ended `select *`, for example.

Have a look at the ['explain plan'](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) for the types of queries you anticipate doing, and tune accordingly. If you're interested in the costs of different types of queries, it's often useful to just load a bunch of test data into a test database and then look at the query plans that Postgres comes up with. The relative numbers of the costs of different query plans are an extremely effective guide to where your painpoints will be when you go live.